# Prevent Illustrator from adding pivot points to the selection

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections

The issue is that both direct (<kbd>A</kbd>) and standard (<kbd>V</kbd>) selection tools add central (pivot) points of other objects to the selection that just happen to be encompassed by the selection.

[image]

What I'd like to do is use the selection tools to just select the burgundy rectangle even if my selection area happens to go over the pivot points of other objects.

I could almost swear with 47% certainty that this is not how selection tools in Illustrator worked before.

Is there an option to tell Illustrator to only select anchor points and paths, not pivot points?

Please note, `pivot points` might not be the official name for them but that's how I've always called them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn off the center marker on the **Attributes Panel**. (Window > Attributes)

[image]

With the center point *off* you can only select objects by clicking their paths and dragging over the center of an object *won't* cause a selection (assuming there's no fill applied).

---

<sub>I'd call it a "centroid" but, depending upon the *actual* shape that may not be accurate either. -- "center point" seems to be something everyone understands and agrees upon for AI. It is the center of the AI *bonding box*, but not always the center of the *actual* shape... if that makes sense.</sub>

Comment: This does solve the issue however since it's a per object setting it can become a pretty tedious overhead when working with complex files. Something like a setting to choose default behavior for newly created objects would be really nice. Thank you.

Comment: @brezanac just `Select All` then toggle it. It won't *actually* make *any* other changed to the objects. I don't disagree. A "Global" setting would be nice, but it simply doesn't exist (silly Adobe).

Comment: Yes but the moment I make a new object it will inherit the default setting of displaying the center point.

Comment: You'll have to file a complaint with Adobe. There's really no other option for users. I feel your frustration, but we *all* deal with it.

Comment: The funny part is I've been working with Illustrator over a decade and I could swear this is a behavior that got introduced in recent versions of it. As for complaining to Adobe I've learned that's usually just a waste of time which is why recently I've been looking more and more in the direction of competition such as Affinity Designer etc. Once again, thank you for your assistance. I am marking this one as the answer.

Comment: I have been using AI since the 1980s.. and I too would *swear* it *used* to be a global setting.. either on or off for *all* objects - Like Outline mode.. it's on and then it's off, it's not object independent. But I just tested in CS6 and CC... and well.. either I'm misremembering or they broke it at some point.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround: Select objects in the layers panel (there's a selection dot to click). You can also temporarily lock there those objects that you want to keep out of the dragged selections.

Comment: Working with layers panel in Illustrator has always been a pretty excruciating experience for me so I stuck with using the selection tools directly. Constant locking and unlocking while working with complex drawings would also impose a pretty significant overhead.